# С# WebSocket Дискорд ошибка подключения

Tags: c#, websocket

Получаю входящие сообщения в дискорде через подключение. Но выдает ошибку
**Closed: An exception has occurred while connecting.**

Пытался менять payload, но не все равно та же ошибка. Даже, если убрать payload и просто, чтобы открывалось соединение **socket.Connect();**, то выдает ту же ошибку в консоль.

Подключаюсь по ссылке, которая указана в документации дискорда: "**wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=10&encoding=json**"

Вот основная функция:

```
static void Main()
    {
        string token = "TOKEN";
        var socket = new WebSocket($"wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=10&encoding=json");

        socket.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Обработка входящих сообщений
            Console.WriteLine("Received: " + e.Data);
        };

        socket.OnOpen += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FGGFKGKIJFIGFJIGFKJFGKG");
            string payload = $@"{{
            ""op"": 2,
            ""d"": {{
                ""token"": ""{token}"",
                ""properties"": {{
                    ""$os"": ""windows"",
                    ""$browser"": ""my_library"",
                    ""$device"": ""my_library""
                }}
            }}
        }}";

            socket.Send(payload);
        };

        socket.OnError += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        };

        socket.OnClose += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Closed: " + e.Reason);
        };

        socket.Connect();
    }
```

Почему вылазит эта ошибка? Что я делаю не так?

Использую пакет **WebSocketSharp**

Comment: Основная ваша проблема в том, что вы городите свои костыли, когда есть готовые, проверенные годами решения. Другая ваша проблема в том, что вы не умеете читать ошибки, ибо то, что в вопросе это дословно переводится как "При подключении возникло исключение", вам сервер должен дать подробное описание ошибки, и как минимум статус код, по которым вы можете понять что не так. Третья проблема в том, что вы не прочитали документацию, где сказано, что вы должны после подключения отправить [сердцебиение](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#sending-heartbeats), а не авторизацию.

Comment: А и еще, перед всеми подключениями, вы должны запросить у API [адрес](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#connecting), и если это бот, то запрос на `/gateway/bot` должен быть вызван с токеном, а уже к полученному адресу вы должны подключаться.

Comment: Решил добавлением строчки **socket.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;**